# Capture Title Case Group in Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to capture the Title Case from my paragraph
The Title Case example is

**Admit to Patient** bla bla bla bla

**Hello There**  bla bla bla bla

**Get There by Noon**  bla bla bla bla

**Get There By Noon** please don't be late

**Hello for Everyone on Here** hope you are doing good

**Hello For Everyone On Here** hope you are doing good

**Admit To Patient** should be matched

From the examples above , all words for title case are capitalized in the first letter except for: a, an, the, at, by, for, in, of, on, to, up, and, as, but, it, or, nor (which can be capitalized but do not have to be)

Can some one help me on getting the regex for this.

```
 private static final String titleCase= *your regex here* 

 static final Pattern titleCasePattern = Pattern.compile(titleCase);
 Matcher match = titleCasePattern .matcher(text);

 while (match.find())
 {
    String match= match.group(1); //This should give me the title case group which is Admit to Patient,Hello There..etc
 }
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to match. Can you provide an example? Do you want to match all words you enumerated? Or everything except for those words?

Comment: I mean -- you gave an example in code, but not in data. If text contains "Admit to Patient bla bla bla", what should match.group(1) return -- "Admit to Patient", or the "bla bla bla"? Inhowfar do the enumerated words play a role? Sorry, I really don´t get it.

Comment: match.group(1) should give me Admit to Patient or  Hello There or Get There by Noon.

Comment: Now clarify "all words for title case are capitalized in the first letter except for: a, an, the, at, by, for, in, of, on, to, up, and, as, but, it, or, nor (which can be capitalized but do not have to be)", and integrate all that into your question. Please.

Comment: I have edited my answer the bold one's on my example should be captured in match.group(1)

Comment: Are the title case words always at the beginning of the String?

Comment: @Disco 3 Good question. Yes they are always at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern (assuming you only want to match ASCII letters; if not, use `\p{Lu}` instead of `[A-Z]` for uppercase and `\p{Ll}` instead `[a-z]` for lowercase letters, and compile the regex using the `Pattern.UNICODE` option) should work:

```
(?:                                # Start of group:
 \b                                # Match start of a word
 (?:                               # Start of inner group:
  [A-Z][a-z]*                      # Either match an uppercase word
 |                                 # or
  (?:a[nts]|the|by|for|i[nt]|      # one of these "special" words
     o[fnr]|to|up|and|but|nor)
 )                                 # End of inner group
 \b                                # Match end of word
 \s+                               # Match one or more whitespace characters
)+                                 # Match one or more of the above.
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/nJ3iE3).

In Java, don't forget to escape the backslashes correctly:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:                             # Start of group:\n" +
    " \\b                            # Match start of a word\n" +
    " (?:                            # Start of inner group:\n" +
    "  [A-Z][a-z]*                   # Either match an uppercase word\n" +
    " |                              # or\n" +
    "  (?:a[nts]|the|by|for|i[nt]|   # one of these 'special' words\n" +
    "     o[fnr]|to|up|and|but|nor)                                \n" +
    " )                              # End of inner group\n" +
    " \\b                            # Match end of word\n" +
    " \\s+                           # Match one or more whitespace characters\n" +
    ")+                              # Match one or more of the above.", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subject);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

Comment: Tim Pietzcker Thanks for your detailed answer with comments. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: Looks useful. And +1 for the crazy in-regexp-inline comments (will that work as shown?).

Comment: @TheBlastOne: Yes, that's what the `Pattern.COMMENTS` flag is for.